# Xlwings + Excel + Python3 Formula guidance

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, sublimetext3, xlwings

(Python3, Sublime Text3, Anaconda, XLWINGS)
Google Doc Of Excel to simplify what my question is

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lMptWhE6MjvK0_S4J25kzDRwl45oEfqSceZR5POYcJ8/edit?usp=sharing

I'm looking for help to go from excel -> python -> excel for a simple mock project I made up. Link to image that explains my goal in less than 10 seconds(

In short I have a list in excel, I want python function to ask for a range that apples to the list (column b) in excel, import the rows that fit said range, use a basic formula to analyze column d and e values ((.4*user test score)+(.6*participation)), and export back into excel the full rows of the top two scores (that the function has calculated). Output is just the identical rows of the top two test takers within my given range

Note: This isn't for any assignment, but just for self-learning. Getting spine surgery so have time on my hands. I don't expect someone to provide a solution as I am sure you are all much busier than I, but helpful links (I couldn't find many relevant given this is so simple) would be good. While I have a lot of docs on Python3, rather lacking on XLWINGS integration with Sublime text.

**Thank you**

Note I know this can be done in Excel and Exclusively VBA, but this is more to learn about integration with a simple demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It outputs on a new sheet instead of old, but works fine.

G is the column row of the table i want to sort by, and D3/D2 are range inputs

```
Sub Range()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Model As Worksheet


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
Set One = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model")

If Not IsEmpty(One.Range("D2")) And Not IsEmpty(One.Range("D3")) Then
    With ws
        .Range("$G$7:$G$" & .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:=">" & One.Range("D2").Value, _
            Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:="<" & One.Range("D3").Value
    End With
End If

End Sub
```